# PHP Onine Shop With Instant Delivery from scratch

Tags: php, mysql

Has anyone made an online shop that uses php/mysql to instantly deliver a product by email after payment through Paypal?

I'm looking into doing this from **scratch**, not using a app or something similar.

**Anybody with experience please link me in the right direction.**

Comment: what have you done so far, what are you stuck on? Or do you want the whole solution?

Comment: StackOverflow is a outlet for answerable questions.  Check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned Paypal, start with their integration section:

- https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview

Otherwise, pick a framework, or build from scratch using PHP/mysql.  Hard to give you anything else without a more detailed question.